# sumifs reference to different worksheets in one workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in the pictures above i made a simplified example of the problem

so the formula that produces the 11

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B2:B30,Sheet1!A2:A30,">="&B3,Sheet1!A2:A30,"<="&C3)
```

but lets say i want to put the formula in sheet 3 how would i adapt the 
`">="&B3,Sheet1!A2:A30,"<="&C3)` part
[image]
[image]

Comment: *B9 IS CURRENT DATE* vs. *F5 and G5 are on another worksheet*. Are you talking about G5 or B9? You are missing **&** in the top formula. `=SUMIFS(LOGBOOK!G9:G73095,LOGBOOK!B9:B73095,">='&DATA '!F5",LOGBOOK!B9:B73083,"<='&DATA '!G5")`

Comment: =SUMIFS(G9:G73095,LOGBOOK!B9:B73095,">="&F5,LOGBOOK!B9:B73095,"<="&G5) the problem i have is if i put the  F5 and G5 cell on another worksheet  the above formula doesnt work because i have to reference that worksheet  ,">="&F5,LOGBOOK!B9:B73095,"<="&G5) so how do i change this to reference >=F5 and <=G5 in the DATA worksheet

Comment: `=SUMIFS(LOGBOOK!G9:G73095, LOGBOOK!B9:B73095,">="&'DATA'!F5", LOGBOOK!B9:B73083,"<="&'DATA'!G5") ` (sorry, I screwed up the syntax a bit in the earlier comment) I do not understand why the `'` are necessary. It almost looks like Data has a trailing space. The ticks are necessary only when the worksheet name has a space.

Comment: i simplified the question

Comment: I regret that I simply cannot see what is difficult about this. Please see a live example of your revised question " [SUMIFS reference to different worksheets in one workbook](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=161352CE07628E22!3501&authkey=!AKeYS9zz5wo5Neo&ithint=file%2cxlsx)

Comment: Its working now but i cant quite understand why it asks me to update values after i select the workbook and then the data worksheets the formula changes from this =SUMIFS(LOGBOOK!G9:G21,LOGBOOK!B9:B21, ">="&'DATA '!F5, LOGBOOK!G9:G21, "<="&'DATA '!G5) to this =SUMIFS(LOGBOOK!G9:G21,LOGBOOK!B9:B21, ">="&'[DATA]DATA '!F5, LOGBOOK!G9:G21, "<="&'[DATA]DATA '!G5)

Comment: Go back and look at the name of your DATA worksheet. It has a trailing space or non-breaking space. You can see it in the formula. Rename the worksheet properly.

Comment: i checked no spaces in the name not before and not after.but thanks for your help its working now